# Call hidden FileUpload control on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, buttonclick

I have a `FileUpload` control on my asp.net page which is hidden

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" />
```

I want this control to be called when user clicks the `Browse` button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="BrowseButton" text="browse" />
```

Is it possible to give control to the `FileUpload` control everytime user clicks the `browse` button?

**EDITED:**

On `BrowseButton_Click` event I want to get upload the file

```
 protected void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('done');</script>");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('please choose');</script>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Control to be called means what. Do yo want to open FileDialog to save file or what exactly. It's not clear what are you asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this at **client side using jQuery**. Please find below code:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server"  CssClass="hidden" />

<asp:Button runat="server" id="BrowseButton" text="browse" OnClientClick="openfileDialog();return false"/>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   function openfileDialog() {
       $("#FileUploadControl").click();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I've added it to `BrowseButton click event`

Comment: It has a compilation error on 
`<asp:Button runat="server" id="BrowseButton" text="browse" onclick="openfileDialog();" />`

Comment: @Nuke Sorry my bad change it to `OnClick` to `OnClientClick`

Comment: Nope, Still doesn't open the dialog box

Comment: $("$FileUploadControl") should be  $("#FileUploadControl")

Comment: Works like a charm , Thanks :)